# Assigned IP address

Tags: google-compute-engine

I need to deploy a virtual machine but no matter what Europe-west1 option I choose I am automatically assigned an US IP address. But I need an IP from Europe. Because websites I need to access do not allow US IP.

I checked in the settings but could not find how to specify IP address location of virtual machine. Can someone please explain to me how to do that?

Comment: All Google Cloud Platform IP addresses are registered at the Google HG in Mountain view, US. This is an administrative registration (whois) and doesn't tell where the actual server is.

Answer (score 0):

As Lennert mentioned Google Cloud Platform IP addresses are registered at Google’s HQ Mountain view, US address and it is for the whois record purpose only. Check [the link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones/) where it is mentioned that europe-west1 geographical locations are in Belgium (Europe) and it is already implemented. From the virtual machine, you will not be able to change the geolocation of the IP. Check with the website contacts and tell them how they determine IP address geolocation. If they consider whois record as proof of geolocation, then, unfortunately, you will not be able to access the websites at the moment. There is a feature request with engineering team but currently I do not have ETA to share.